# Microsoft Lightswitch Application hangs when screen resolution is 1024 x 768

Tags: silverlight, visual-studio-lightswitch

I have created a Lightswitch desktop application which works fine on all resolutions higher than 1024 x 768. Unfortunately I need to hook it up to a projector which only supports 1024 x 768 and as a result the application hangs. According to Microsoft you need a resolution of 1024 x 768 or higher as a requirement for Lightswitch. Has anyone else experienced this or have any ideas as to how to resolve the issue?